# How to convert varchar into datetime and skip not valid datetime in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a database in SQL Server. I do not have authorization to change any table but I can create views.

I have three `varchar` columns which store dates in the format `YYYYMMDD`. I want to create a view where the dates are converted from `varchar` to `datetime`.

Now it can be the case that instead of a date in this columns I can have empty space, `NULL` or the character `-`.

Let's take the `closedDate` column. If I use `CONVERT(datetime, closedDate, 112)`

1. Valid dates are converted correctly,
2. When there is empty space the date is converted to `1900-01-01`,
3. NULL is kept,
4. The `-` causes a conversion error:

> *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.*

How can I tell to the function to convert dates just if it has valid date form and leave NULL or better an empty date(or space) in all the other cases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(closedDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, closedDate, 112) 
     ELSE NULL END closedDate
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! And if instead of NULL I want to get empty date/space?

Comment: You cannot have an empty space in a datetime field.

Comment: Oh I don't know that there is ISDATE() function. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Use below code    


    SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(datecolumn)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, datecolumn, 103 ) 
                        ELSE null END
            FROM tablename


 use below for empty data

    SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(datecolumn)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, datecolumn, 103 ) 
                            ELSE '' END
                FROM tablename
```

Comment: The second example will not work as expected.  SQL (TSQL PL/SQL) must choose a data type for the row output - and since the column appears to be datetime - then all values must be converted to datetime.   And an empty string '' converted to datetime returns "1900-01-01 00:00:00" on SQL Server (and I'll bet the same on Oracle).

Comment: yes it will return default date 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000